# Can Sequelize models be reused to dynamically create tables

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am currently using nodejs and (learning!) the ORM capabilities of Sequelize with SQL Server.  I have a scenario where I want to create database tables specific to an organisation when they register to the site.  I have had a look at sequelize-auto to generate models based on the database, but over time this would result in a huge number of models.  Is it possible to reuse model definitions to create tables with specified table names, and then to run queries based on the organisation?

For example organisation foo registers to the site, a table fooMembers is created.  Queries resulting from usage by a member of foo are directed to the fooMembers table.

Comment: but why would you do that? Isn't better to use a foreign key of Organization id on the member table?

Comment: That is what is currently happening.  Having thought about it I now wonder whether I need to be thinking about isolated databases as opposed to isolated tables.  I was thinking about flexibility and that it may be easier to distribute across servers, having organisations on different versions, easier to backup data, if one database is down it doesn't affect everyone...

Comment: There is no way where making multiple tables works. Just do one table and make the relationship.

Comment: Why would it never work?

Comment: Because that's not the way as a Relational Database works, That's not scalable in any scenario, I actually don't understand where and how create different tables for users will work.